# Trying to parse a json with several arrays inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is my Index.html

```
<div id="#here">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&depth=30", function(data){
  var x = data.asks
  $.each(x, function(index, item) {
    //console.log(item);
    $('#here').append("<p>"+ item +"</p>");
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

i'm just trying to parse a json an put inside a `p`.

in the console the script runs ok

[image: Printscreen]

help guys, pleas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is an array so you need to access the array element using brackets notation like so:

```
item[0]
```

You also want to remove the `#` symbol from the `id` attribute of your `div` element.
The `id` attribute value must begin with a letter.

So this should work.

**--HTML--**

```
<div id="here"></div>
```

**--JS--**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&depth=30", function(data) {
  var x = data.asks;

  $.each(x, function(index, item) {

    var $paragraph = $('<p>');
    $paragraph.text(item[0])
    $('#here').append($paragraph);

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: I just tried it in a fiddle and it worked just fine.

Comment: Sure, have fun. ☺